# OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT on Java aes decryption

Tags: python, java, encryption, aes, cbc-mode

I'm tyring to encrypt the connection between a python and a java script and to do that I have a encryption and decryption function in each side, python and java scripts both can decrypt the encrypted message by themselves and also python's decryption function can decrypt the encrypted message by java but the problem is java can't decrypt the encrypted message by python and also getting this error during decryption:

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

and also another problem is for the same message python's encrypted message length is longer by 16 bytes which I couldn't figure out why.

Here is the encryption and decryption functions in java script:

```
public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        String stringIV = getRandomIV();
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(stringIV.getBytes());
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(privateKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream( );
        outputStream.write( stringIV.getBytes() );
        outputStream.write( encrypted );
        byte c[] = outputStream.toByteArray( );
        String encryptedString = new String(encrypted, "utf-8");
        String toEncrypt = stringIV + encryptedString;
        return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(c, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        byte[] base64decoded = new byte[0];
        base64decoded = android.util.Base64.decode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        byte[] byteiv = new byte[16];
        byteiv = Arrays.copyOfRange(base64decoded, 0, 16);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(byteiv);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(privateKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] bytemsg = new byte[base64decoded.length - 16];
        bytemsg = Arrays.copyOfRange(base64decoded, 16, base64decoded.length);
        byte[] original = new byte[base64decoded.length - 16];
        try{
            original = cipher.doFinal(bytemsg);
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.i("Decryption Error", e.toString());
        }
        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

static String getRandomIV() {
    UUID randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    return randomUUID.toString().replaceAll("_", "").replaceAll("-", "").substring(0,16);
}
```

and here is the encryption and decryption functions in python script:

```
def decrypt(message):
    msg=bytes(message).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
    decodedMsg=base64.b64decode(msg)
    cipher = AES.new(self.inits['key'].encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, decodedMsg[0:16])
    decoded = cipher.decrypt(decodedMsg[16:])
    decoded = bytes(decoded).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
    return decoded

def encrypt(data):
    iv = Random.get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher = AES.new(self.inits['key'].encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    bytearrayIV= bytearray(iv)
    encrypted = bytearray(cipher.encrypt(self.pad(data).encode("utf8")))
    encrypted = base64.b64encode(bytes(bytearrayIV+encrypted))
    encrypted = list(data)
    encrypted = bytes(data)
    return encrypted

def pad(self, msg):
    while len(msg)%32 != 0:
        msg = msg + " "
    return msg
```

I also tried to pass `base64.b64encode(bytes(bytearrayIV+encrypted)).decode()` as output in python's encryption function and the error didn't occur but the decrypted message on java was a long string of �

So I will be much appreciated if you help me with this.

Comment: `getRandomIV()` on the Java side and `pad()` on the Python side are missing. Also, why are there three different values assigned to `encrypted` in the `encrypt()` function on the Python side? Using my own implementations of the missing functions the codes seem to be compatible, so possibly a bug in the `pad()` function. Btw, in the Python `decrypt()` function the unpadding is missing.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks for your answer, I have edited and added those functions,I know the pad() and getRandomIV() can be written in a more right way, also I'm getting results with this pad() function in encryption between this python script and a c script for encryption/decryption already but not in java.

Comment: Your `pad()` function does not implement PKCS#7/PKCS#5 padding and must be replaced. The easiest way is to use the [padding module](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#crypto-util-padding-module) of PyCryptodome (block size is 16 bytes for AES). Don't forget the unpadding in `decrypt()`. Run your tests again after you have made these changes. Btw, the `encrypt()` function still has the three overwriting assignments to `encrypted` (so it won't work).

Comment: @Topaco Thank you so much, using PyCryptodome padding module fixed the problem, you saved a lot of time for me , if you are interested please post this so I can approve that as answer.